# Radar simulator

Tags: game-engine

Do you know if I can do something like a marine radar in blender, detecting figures in the world (like cubes moving around) and showing them in a display. (seeing both, the radar display and the world). Like in a FPS game :P.

Comment: do you basically want a mini-map with the cubes?

Comment: yes, something like that, but with a "real" map, can you help me please??